# POST Request for Docker Compose File in GitHub Actions

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am running services from a docker compose file and trying to test it using GitHub Actions. I am able to make a [GET request](https://github.com/RohanSasne/pecan/actions/runs/5223587597/jobs/9430653728#step:9:1) successfully, but I am not able to make a [POST request](https://github.com/RohanSasne/pecan/actions/runs/5223446882/jobs/9430317172#step:9:7). It redirects me to a wrong URL. Also it first gives me a 307 status code before being redirected.

The post request is running totally fine in my local system. The response screenshot is as follows:

[image: error]

Comment: Well it turns out one of the service was crashing after initial startup, solved the issue now.

For people facing the same issue in the future, set the service to restart until it's manually stopped: restart: `restart: unless-stopped`